# Unable to verify signature when keys are strongbox backed in Android Keystore

Tags: android, cryptography, android-keystore, pki

My requirement is to sign sha256 hash using keys generated in AndroidKeystore. but when I verify the signature validity it fails here are my observations using different scenarios.

we have tested this in the following scenarios using Google PIXEL 3A as  strongbox enabled device

```
IsStrongBoxEnabled   Algorithm    Verification
   TRUE             NONEWithRSA      FALSE
   TRUE             SHA256WithRSA    TRUE
   FALSE            NONEWithRSA      TRUE
   FALSE            SHA256WithRSA    TRUE
   TRUE             NONEWithECDSA    TRUE
   TRUE             SHA256WithECDSA  TRUE
   FALSE            NONEWithECDSA    TRUE
   FALSE            SHA256WithECDSA  TRUE
```

Here is my sample test code

```
package com.company.samplekeystoreapp;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.security.keystore.StrongBoxUnavailableException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.RSAKeyGenParameterSpec;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private KeyPair keyPair;
private KeyStore keyStore;
private String aliasName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

        aliasName = "keyPrefix_" + uuid.toString();
        keyPair = generateKeyPair(true);

        KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(aliasName, null);
        if (!(entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)) {
            Log.w("SampleApp", "Not an instance of a PrivateKeyEntry");
        }

        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
        if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
            s.initSign(((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey());
        }

        byte[] data = Hex.decode("d56ca469cd129c015f682724560baaf653914ef21fff1817512186d67b18c7f5");
        s.update(data);
        byte[] signature = s.sign();


        if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
            s.initVerify(((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getCertificate());
        }
        s.update(data);
        boolean valid = s.verify(signature);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Status : " + valid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private KeyPair generateKeyPair(boolean isStrongBoxEnabled) throws Exception {
    try{
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && isStrongBoxEnabled) {
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            aliasName, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512, KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1)
                            .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)
                            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .build());
        } else {
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            aliasName, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512, KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1)
                            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .build());
        }
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof StrongBoxUnavailableException) {
            try {
              return  keyPair = generateKeyPair(false);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 throw e;               
            }   
        }else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And ... what happens? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Exception is not thrown but upon verifying the signature verify method returns false.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the actual device, and the android emulator for that device does not include strongbox emulation, so I can't work on the problem.